# Beta fish sleeping or sick?

Tags: aquarium, fish, betta

I have had my Beta fish for almost 2 years, he didn’t look great when I first got him but after 1 week I got a 5 gallon tank with a low flow filter and a heater. He has since then always ate well and had a lot of energy and had really pretty fins.

He has lots of fake plants and loves his little cave. But lately, he has been just staying at the bottom of his cave, to the point where I didn’t see him for like 4 days (I feed him every day or every other day about 2 pellets although he sometimes eats 3 within 2 minutes) His tank is at about 75-80ish Fahrenheit, I did a 1/2 water change a couple weeks ago, and always let it sit until the water clears up (without him innit) for one or two days after I put in his ph level tablet in, and sometimes the conditioner if I use tap water...

I just cleaned the glass and removed his cave, and put in his little hammock in hopes he will hang out near the top and notice some food. He seems to be eating a lot less. He did swim around and inspect everything though...

What could be wrong and what can I do???

He started being less active when my cat scared him and tries to chase him through the glass. I try my best to not let him do this and he isnt aloud in the room without me there. I understand it could be stress but other than not letting it happen again I don’t know how to make him better.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think this will be due to swim bladder disease 
To cure this you can feed them with fresh boiled green peas 
Symptoms are that fish becomes pale colour, it will only lie on the base.
If our bettas tail is wrinkled ,it will be due to the climatic conditions ,
I think you should use a Aquarium heater
And also use a oxygen filter because due to swim bladder disease they can't swim around...